# Connecting to Regtest

Tags: bitcoind, regtest

I want to connect to a local node that I have set up in regtest mode using bitcoind. The node I am connection from is non bitcoind and I need to set the port that I want the peer discovery to take place from. What parameters do I need to set in my bitcoin.conf for bitcoind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default port for bitcoin regtest is `18444`. You can set a custom port with `port=<port>` in your `bitcoin.conf` or by passing `-port=<port>` as argument.